# Remove user from SharePoint site in C#

Tags: c#, .net, sharepoint-online, csom

I need to remove users from SharePoint site collection in C#/.NET. Here is the link for PowerShell code, but I need to write it in C#.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/remove-users

The below code is not working.

```
 private void RemoveUser(String user)
 {
    using (SPSite sps = new SPSite("http://serverName"))
            {
                using (SPWeb spWeb = sps.RootWeb)
                {
                    SPUserCollection spuc = sps.RootWeb.AllUsers;
                    spuc.Remove(user);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Refer to the sample c# code snippet for deleting users: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/manage-sharepoint-users-and-groups#add-and-remove-groups-and-users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have one SharePoint site named **sridemosite** with members like below:

**From the SharePoint Admin Center:**

[image]

**From the SharePoint Portal:**

[image]

To **remove a user** from this SharePoint site collection in .NET, I used the below code:

```cs
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Security;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;

namespace CSOMAuthentication
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Provide Site URL
            string SiteURL = "https://xxxxxxxxxxx.sharepoint.com/sites/sridemosite";
            string Environmentvalue = "o365";
            string username = "admin@xxxxxxxxxx.onmicrosoft.com";
            string password = "xxxxxxxxxxx";
            AuthenticateUser(new Uri(SiteURL), Environmentvalue, username, password);
        }

        private static void AuthenticateUser(Uri TargetSiteUrl, string Environmentvalue, string username, string password)
        {
            try
            {
                // Based on the environmentvalue provided it execute the function.
              if (string.Compare(Environmentvalue, "o365", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == 0)
                {
                    ClientContext Context = O365LogOn(username, password, TargetSiteUrl);

                    Group oGroup = Context.Web.SiteGroups.GetByName("sridemosite Members");

                    // Get user using Logon name
                    User oUser = Context.Web.EnsureUser("devi@xxxxxxxxxxxx.onmicrosoft.com");

                    Context.Load(oUser);
                    Context.ExecuteQuery();

                    // Remove user from the group
                    oGroup.Users.RemoveByLoginName(oUser.LoginName);
                    
                    Context.ExecuteQuery();         
                }  
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // log error               
            }
        }

        private static ClientContext O365LogOn(string userName, string password, Uri url)
        {
            ClientContext clientContext = null;
            ClientContext ctx = null;
            try
            {
                clientContext = new ClientContext(url);

                // Condition to check whether the user name is null or empty.
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(userName) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(password))
                {
                    SecureString securestring = new SecureString();
                    password.ToCharArray().ToList().ForEach(s => securestring.AppendChar(s));
                    clientContext.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(userName, securestring);
                    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
                }
                else
                {
                    clientContext.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
                    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
                }
                ctx = clientContext;
            }
            finally
            {
                if (clientContext != null)
                {
                    clientContext.Dispose();
                }
            }
            return ctx;    
        }
    }
}
```

**Response:**

[image]

To **confirm** that, I checked the same in both Portals where the **`Devi`** user removed successfully from site collection like below:

**From the SharePoint Admin Center:**

[image]

**From the SharePoint Portal:**

[image]

**References:**

[Remove User From Site Group in SharePoint using CSOM - Code SharePoint](https://www.codesharepoint.com/csom/remove-user-from-site-group-in-sharepoint-using-csom)

[Connect to SharePoint Online, On premise and Extranet using CSOM - Code SharePoint](https://www.codesharepoint.com/sharepoint-tutorial/connect-to-sharepoint-online-on-premise-and-extranet-using-csom)

Comment: This is rather dangerous and bad practice--you have hardcoded not just your SharePoint admin username and password, making them interceptable, but also meaning anyone who runs this will impersonate you, violating all kinds of audit and compliance requirements. Not to mention, any time your password changes, you'll have to come here and re-compile or re-deploy the application with the new credential. At the _very_ least, the credentials should be in a non-accessible file, but ideally you should just prompt the user running the web app to provide their own credentials at runtime.